# Glew on x64 program using Visual Studio on Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, glew

I am trying for few days now to work out a solution to my problem. At first I thought it was quite small one but i am simply running out of ideas.

I am using x64 platform for my program. I had to download windows SDK 7.1 to get GLM and GLFW working. I am trying to use GLEW 1.10.0 Binaries which i downloaded from

http://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/1.10.0/glew-1.10.0-win32.zip/download

I have downloaded, and put header files and lib files in (I think) proper folders, there is no issue with compiling the program, but when I type in my code every time I end up with message that it failed to initialize.

```
glewExperimental = true;
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
```

I think my libraries are ok

I added "C:\Users***\Desktop\Projekt\glew-1.10.0\lib\Release\x64" to "VC++ Directories/Library Directories" and glew32.lib to my Additional Dependencies in "Linker/Input"

If you have any additional questions or advice let me know.

Comment: What is exact value returned by glewInit? It has GLenum type, this can give some information. Ensure that GLEW 64 bit libraries (dll) are available through PATH or by any other way. Library Directories are used at linking time, make appropriate environment settings also for runtime.

Comment: Sorry for not writing back during christmas :)

Here is what i have in glewInit
glewInit 0x000000013fb9506c glewInit void *

Comment: I am afraid that  Binaries [_link_](https://sourceforge.net/projects/glew/files/glew/1.10.0/glew-1.10.0-win32.zip/download) are not created for VS 10 but VS 6, but maybe i am going astray